# Cease doing/to do

Tags: gerunds

Could you say if *cease* can be used with both infinitives and gerunds. I first searched for some examples via Reverso Context, and there are examples with both gerunds and infinitives, so I want to ensure that it's really true with your wise help, Owls.

1. When a person gets shot, they cease [to live/living].
2. After you have had sex, you cease [to be/being] a virgin.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the question is moot, because *cease* is not the word to use.

*Fowler* (3rd Edition, ed. Burchfield, OUP 1988) has

> **cease.** This 14c. loanword from French
> is slowly yielding to *stop* except in a few
> set phrases, e.g. *without cease,* unending;
> *cease-fire,* an order to stop firing; a period
> of truce. The natural idiom is *to stop
> breathing* not *to cease breathing,* and *to stop
> work,* not *to cease work.* But the battle
> between the two words is far from over
> and they look like coexisting for a long
> time to come.

Not only is *stop* preferable to *cease,* but *cease being* (or *stop being*) might be better expressed as *[are] no longer:*

> After you have had sex, you are no longer a virgin.

However, *Fowler* can also provide the answer, as it includes *cease breathing.* If you must use *cease,* pair it with a gerund.

Now, because *cease* is on the way out, it currently has a literary/poetic effect. As pointed out in comments, one can idiomatically *cease to be* rather than *cease being*, so

> After you have had sex, you cease to be a virgin.

But, as a general rule, *cease* is followed by a gerund or a  noun — *cease breathing; cease work.*

Comment: Nevertheless, [cease to be](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cease+to+be) is an idiom.

Comment: @KateBunting When one pines for the fjords, perhaps. I think one can still (just, poetically) "cease to be" = "die". Or you can cease to be something ("If you eat that letter, you will cease to be a postman!", so *virgin* might work, but again that's for literary effect). One can't cease **to be doing something.**

Comment: I didn't say you could; I was only suggesting that _cease_ doesn't have to be followed by a gerund.